# jQuery ajax drops integer on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, put

I am using this data...

```
 // Pulled from the button that was hit
 var method = document.activeElement.getAttribute('method').toUpperCase(); 
 var url = document.activeElement.getAttribute('url');
```

Both buttons (methods) have the same url defined... **'/user/1'**

This is my jQuery AJAX call...

```
 $.ajax({
   type: method,
   url: url',   /* I even hard coded this to make sure what it had to use */
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: $(form).serializeArray(),
   error: function (xhr, status) {
     alert(xhr.status + ' : ' + url);
   }
 });
```

I have discovered that a PUT call truncates the number at the end of the given URL. But it has a trailing SLASH, it's OK.

If I run DELETE, it does what I expect

```
DELETE: /user/1
```

If I run PUT, I don;t get what I expect...

```
PUT: /user
```

notice the number "1" missing from that url?

I dug around and decided to try native JS... this is what I have...

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open(method, url);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 xhr.onload = function() {
   if (xhr.status === 200) {
     var userInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   }
 };
 xhr.send(JSON.stringify($(form).serializeArray()));
```

If I run DELETE, it does what I expect

```
DELETE: /user/1
```

If I run PUT...

```
PUT: /user/1
```

It works.

Yes, I know the URL has the "1" at the end for a PUT because I am sending the variable to the console before AND after the ajax call.

```
console.log(method + ': ' + url);
```

Besides, its the same var creation used for the native JS as used for the jQuery.

Now here's the kicker!

If the URL is defined as...

```
PUT: /user/walter
```

The name at the end stays.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like some bug.Did you try in any other browser?

Comment: This works fine in Firefox.

Comment: ...so what is the question? how to do this with jquery? can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?